# Polkadot-JS: Retrieve return type of a query operation dynamically

Tags: polkadot-js

Given the following code sample

```
api.query.system.account
```

I'd like to know the key prefix constituents, i.e. `System` + `Account` and the type this operation will return as a string, i.e. `FrameSystemAccountInfo`.

Is there a possibility in polkadotjs API to retrieve this type information somehow?

PS: I'm currently retrieving the key prefix constituents via:

```js
const { prefix, method } = api.query.system.account.creator.toJSON().storage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`api.query.<pallet>.<call>.creator.meta` has the metadata as retrieved from the chain.

To lookup the specific type there, you can do

```js
const meta = api.query.system.account.creator.meta

/ * FrameSystemAccountInfo */
console.log(api.registry.lookup.getName(meta.type.asMap.value))
```

Comment: Thanks! And in case of plain values, is there also a lookup defined somewhere?